# List to int in python

Tags: python, integer

I am wondering if there is a nice way to convert a list of digits to an integer in python. That is, if I have `mylist = [1, 5, 9]` I would like to do something like `int(mylist)` to get an output of `159`. I am assuming that the input list simply has digits, and I want to use this to create a number. Currently the best I have is:

```
mylist = [1, 5, 9]
num = 0
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    num += mylist[i] * 10 ** (len(mylist) - i - 1)
```

Which should work alright, but feels too explicit. Is there a neater/nicer way to do this?

Comment: `num = int(''.join([str(item) for item in mylist]))`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider how your data got into that structure and fix that.

But you can easily combine it as a string and call `int()` on it:

```
int("".join(str(i) for i in mylist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best I can think of is:

```
mylist = [1, 5, 9]
num = 0
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    num += mylist[i] * 10 ** (len(mylist) - i - 1)
```

Comment: Isn't this the exact same code as in your question?

Comment: @Chris Yes it is. I just figured that since it accomplishes the task, I ought to add as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
list = [1, 2, 3]
string = ''
for num in list:
    string = string + str(num)
result = int(string)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The map function is generally faster. I used a lambda, but you could also just create your own function instead of a lambda.

```
mylist = [1, 5, 9]
N = len(mylist)
sum(list(map(lambda x : x[0]*10**(N-x[1]-1),  enumerate(mylist))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

assert reduce(lambda a, x: 10*a + x, [1,5,9]) == 159
```

This is a short way of implementing [Horner's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).